# Connection timeout when accessing https for calling webservices in Android

Tags: android, https, connection, timeout

The connection to Web Service is working fine for http protocol but when changed to https it throws Connection Time out exception. The services do work on Desktop browser but not on Android emulator either from the app or through emulator browser.

What can be the reason for this behavior? The https site for twitter does gets open for on emulator.

Thanks

Comment: I have been able to make https work on the device but its still a problem on the emulator. Can anyone suggests what can be the issue that https is not working on emulator from browser as well as through the app?

Comment: I have been able to figure out that if emulator is configured to use proxy then emulator browser can make https request to the server but the app will still not be able to make https connection. This is really a weird problem.